# React-native: Android version crashes on start

Tags: android, react-native

I am quiet frustrated since I always tested using the iOS simulator. However, today I tried installing it on my Android device for the app to crash INSTANTLY on boot-up. I get no error messages, no feedback, nada.

I have been trying to read through stackoverflow but nothing has helped.
On iOS it works perfectly, so my thinking is that it has nothing to do with the JavaScript side of things but some configuration error or something. How can I move on from here?

PLEASE, any help is appreciated. I am willing to .zip the file anyone with more Android development knowledge than I do.

I have no clue what to do. Here are my Android files (the relevant ones):

`app/build.gradle`:

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.lisdoworker"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    manifestPlaceholders = [
        tipsiStripeRedirectScheme: "example"
    ]
}
splits {
    abi {
        reset()
        enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
        universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
        include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
}
// applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
        // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
        def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
        def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
        if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
            output.versionCodeOverride =
                    versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
        }
    }
}
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':tipsi-stripe')
    compile project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android')
    compile project(':react-native-google-places')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

My `settings.gradle`:

```
rootProject.name = 'lisdoWorker'
include ':tipsi-stripe'
project(':tipsi-stripe').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/tipsi-stripe/android')
include ':react-native-extra-dimensions-android'
project(':react-native-extra-dimensions-android').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-extra-dimensions-android/android')
include ':react-native-google-places'
project(':react-native-google-places').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-google-places/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
include ':react-native-linear-gradient'
project(':react-native-linear-gradient').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android')
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-fetch-blob'
project(':react-native-fetch-blob').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fetch-blob/android')
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
include ':app'
```

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.lisdoworker;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Intent;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.gettipsi.stripe.StripeReactPackage;
import ca.jaysoo.extradimensions.ExtraDimensionsPackage;
import com.arttitude360.reactnative.rngoogleplaces.RNGooglePlacesPackage;
import com.oblador.vectoricons.VectorIconsPackage;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.imagepicker.ImagePickerPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new StripeReactPackage(),
          new ExtraDimensionsPackage(),
          new RNGooglePlacesPackage(),
          new VectorIconsPackage(),
          new LinearGradientPackage(),
          new ImagePickerPackage(),
          new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
  }
}
```

npm just in case:

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-native": "0.47.1",
```

Comment: Please do "adb logcat" and start your app. Then post the crash here. Usually this means it is crashing in Android code so you won't see anything useful in RN console error crash.

Comment: To see the Android logs generated by your application you should use the command `react-native log-android` since it'll automatically filter the logcat output for you, leaving only relevant logs. Do that than update your question with the output log.

Comment: Thank you guys!! `adb logcat` mentioned something with FBSDK not being able to read a string and indeed I missed a part of the installation! Thank you so much @sfratini